# Photo by Camera Upload Exception (Firebase Storage)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-camera, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image taken by the camera in an android application to Firebase storage. The problem is that after I take the picture, in the confirmation `activity`, I pressed the confirm button and it says that "Unfortunately the application stopped".

This is the image when I press the check button, and the app crashes...

[image]

This is my code, the application has the option to upload pictures using the gallery and the camera.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// Note: Your consumer key and secret should be obfuscated in your source code before shipping.


private Button selectImage;
private Button selectImageByCamera;
private ImageView imageView;

private StorageReference storageReference;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int GALLERY_INTENT= 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


    /*
    * Code section to upload an image using the Gallery.
    */
    selectImage=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_uploadImg);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    selectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);

        }
    });


    /*
    *  Code section to upload an image using the Camera.
    */

    selectImageByCamera=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_uploadImgCamera);
    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    selectImageByCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });



}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    //Upload the image to Firebase Update
    if(requestCode==GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Image...");
        progressDialog.show();
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        });
    }
        //Code to upload image taken by the camera to firebase storage
        if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Image...");
            progressDialog.show();

            Uri uri2 = data.getData();
            StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child("Photos").child(uri2.getLastPathSegment());

            filepath.putFile(uri2).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
        }


}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I have this USER PERMISSIONS in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

I have this Firebase dependencies in app/build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
```

And finally this is the exception thrown when I run the app in my Moto G4 6.0.1 (The app has permissions to use Camera and Gallery)

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: mx.com.jamba.jamba, PID: 16543
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {mx.com.jamba.jamba/mx.com.jamba.jamba.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference                                                                      
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3720)                                                                       
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3763)                                                                       
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154)                                                                      
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1403)                                                                      
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                      
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                                                       
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)                                                                      
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                      
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)                                                                      
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)                                                                    
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference                                                                      
at mx.com.jamba.jamba.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:186)                                                                      
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6470)                                                                      
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3716)                                                                      
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3763)                                                                      
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154)                                                                      
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1403)                                                                       
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                       
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                                                        
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)                                                                        
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                       
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)                                                                        
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

I don't know what to do, it would be great if you guys to help me :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The exception occurs because the `Uri` in `onActivityResult()` is null:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
```

[The documentation for capturing a camera image](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) explains:

> The Android Camera application saves a full-size photo if you give it
> a file to save into. **You must provide a fully qualified file name
> where the camera app should save the photo**.

Follow the example in the documentation to create a file Uri and add it to the intent for the camera app.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bitmap mImageUri = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        select.setImageBitmap(mImageUri);
    }
```

then start posting